# Cat/baby keyboard protection

Tags: keyboard

is there a way to automatically lock the keyboard (preferably without locking the computer) when several keys are pressed together or held for long, similar to a cat walking on the keyboard or a baby having a fit at your lack of attention towards him...?

I know I can have a shortcut key to start the screensaver, but I'd rather the screen stayed on while I wrestle the little monster to the ground...